# How to search for a full name when first name and last name are stored in a different columns

Tags: mysql

How can I search for a person full name if I have first name stored in a column called "first_name" and the last name is stored in a column called "last_name"

Note that this table has couple million records so I need an efficient way to do the search. and I am using MySQL Server

the column first_name and the column last_name are both type VARCHAR(80).

I have tried the following so far which works but slow because it ignores the indexes because of the concat function

```
SELECT first_name, phone FROM people
WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ',first_name, last_name) like '%John Smith%'
```

I also have tried to add index full text index on( first_name, last_name)
and then this query

```
SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE MATCH(first_name, last_name) AGAINST('John Smith')
```

but it is not the fastest query. is there a better approach to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: With that many records, make sure both the first and last name columns are indexed.

Comment: @Satya I have added the query that I have tried in my question. It is slow.

Comment: @musical_coder the I need to know a query so I can use index. Note that my query is not using indexes because I use CONCAT_WS function

Comment: why use '%John Smith%' when the firstname of a person will be John and LAstname with be Smith

Comment: because I don't know which one is the first name and which one is the last name.

Comment: Where does the string 'John Smith' come from?  A single field on a web form?

Comment: Yes there is, in my answer. If you have a web form with one field, you should consider splitting it up into first and last name fields so you can take advantage of the query I posted. Also, if you do a wildcard search with wildcard preceding the first character, no indices can be used.

Comment: If you want to use indexes you CANNOT use `like` with a leading %. So do you think you will ever be able to NOT use a leading wildcard (%) when searching for a match?  If so, where does the string 'John Smith' come from? Why can't you split it at the space and consider the left part the first name and the right part the last name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a `FULLTEXT` index on `(first_name, last_name)` and use [`MATCH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match)

```
WHERE MATCH(first_name, last_name) AGAINST ('John Smith')
```

Comment: I actually tried that but it is not the fastest. I am trying to see if there a better approach to this problem.

Comment: Hi, this would also allow matches for "Rose Smith", or "John Rogan".  How can I only get results for "John Smith's"?

Answer (score 3):

Try searching each field independently:

```
WHERE first_name = 'James' and last_name = 'Hetfield';
```

I'd also add a composite index for both, using last name first as it would have a higher cardinality (more unique rows), meaning that searching on the last name 'Hetfield' should be faster, than searching on a first name 'James'.

```
ALTER TABLE `some_table` ADD key (`last_name`, `first_name`);
```

Comment: A challenge to this approach is if the user interface is offering a single input box for name search. Since both first and last names could have spaces in them, it would require splitting the string at each space and trying each pair of potential first and last names and unioning the results. That might still be faster than a solution that indexes on the concatenated field, but it's not necessarily intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you want to search performance you should change your approach (Millions and more record need more efficiant solution). Could you use NoSQL or FullText search solutions for partial columns.