# Mysql: Conditional select / concat depending on column matches

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with user details in one table and linked contact details in another table (where the contact details are stored as "content").

I am trying to make a quick search function where you can search for the name or any contact details.  So you can either search for name or an email or phone (whatever is in the contact detail field).

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT leads.id, CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) AS name
FROM `leads` 
INNER JOIN `contact_details` ON contact_details`.`lead_id` = `leads`.`id` 
WHERE ((CONCAT(first_name, last_name, content) LIKE ('%[XXX]%')));
```

This works fine.  You can search for f ex "55" and it will return hits on f ex ph number 555-573-3222 or you can search for a name string like 'Joh' and it will match 'Johnson'.

My problem, though, is that regardless of what you are searching for, what is being returned is client name.  Since this is for an autocomplete feature, this is obviously very confusing.  If you start typing in 555-2 you want to see the suggestion 555-221-6362 not "John Johnson".

1. How can I return EITHER a phone number or email (from column "content") OR the concact first_name, ' ', last_name depending on whether the search matched a name or a contact_detail.content.
2. Since I am searching on first_name OR last_name, the search works well for "joh" matching "John" but obviously breaks when you search for "John Stan" for "John Stanley".  Is there a Mysql way of fixing this or do I need to clean up string before and do alternative searches if there is a space (searching first_name AND last_name separately)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I have struggled with this for days now.

Comment: I think what you are doing is not a good/clean way of coding, however if you want to continue down the path you are going, you can probably find the ability to change your select, by using an if/then (reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html)

Comment: I would love to hear a suggestion for an alternative way of coding this when you require a common search field for multiple columns.  That is not a coding decision but an end user requirement.  

If that can be achieved in a different way that is as quick as a single mysql select, I am willing to learn

Comment: So I would avoid the concats, because you could get positives that comes from searches of the concatenated fields, not exact substrings of one field. So in your where to break your where into 3 likes for each field and use 'OR' to connect them together, that would be the first step. In your select, you'll probably want to do nested if/thens, which would allow you a order of precedence for which field would displayed if the substring is in multiple fields. All done with one query :)

Comment: OK.  Point taken about the concat. Will move them out to separate conditions.

Comment: You understand how to do the nested if/thens too?

Comment: Not yet, but I will try to figure it out and update here. Was playing around with CASE conditions so far

Comment: add an example solution for you, which you'll be able to modify to probably get what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charliez, per our comment conversation, the following is an example of how to do some nested if/thens as well as the break out of the where. You'll need to adjust this to met your specific needs, but should give you enough of an example that you should be able to get things working.

```
SELECT
  IF(last_name LIKE '%JAM%', 
    last_name, 
    IF(first_name LIKE '%JAM%', 
       first_name, 
       ''
      )
    ) AS MatchedFieldText
FROM employee
WHERE 
  last_name LIKE '%JAM%' 
  OR first_name LIKE '%JAM%';
```

Comment: Perfect!  Very much appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) I don't think there is a way to have a `SELECT` statement return something different based on an `OR`. My first thought to solve this would be to return `first, last, content` and use some regex to determine if you should show the name or the number/content.

2) Kind of a hard problem, and I don't think I have seen a perfect solution to it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918323/how-to-search-for-a-full-name-when-first-name-and-last-name-are-stored-in-a-diff) might give you some ideas/put you on the right track.